# json.dumps takes too much time to convert the data

Tags: python, json, django

I am using `json.dumps` to make some reports from my Django model.

```
    start = time.process_time()
    items = Allotment.objects.all().order_by('dispatch_date')
    print("allotments", len(items))
    serializer = AllotmentFloatingSerializer(items, many=True)
    items_json = json.dumps(serializer.data)
    print("allot time", time.process_time() - start)
```

I have checked the time of query and serialization and it comes too small to even notice but `json.dumps` takes too much time, sometimes it's even in the minutes. What should I do to reduce this processing time?

Seralizer.py

```
class FloatingKitsSerialzer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Kit
        fields = ('kit_name', 'kit_type')


class AllotmentFlowsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flow = serializers.SlugRelatedField( read_only=True, slug_field='flow_name')
    kit = FloatingKitsSerialzer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = AllotmentFlow
        fields =('flow', 'kit', 'alloted_quantity')


class AllotmentFloatingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    flows = AllotmentFlowsSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Allotment
        fields = ('transaction_no', 'dispatch_date', 'flows')
```

Comment: are you sure it is not the `serializer.data` property?

Comment: Usually it is *not* a good idea to fetch *all* objects. Pagination is usually used to prevent processing gigantic amounts of data, since this can be used to take a website down.

Comment: Furthermore it is possible that your serializer serializes items linked to by a `ForeignKey` resulting in the N+1 problem. Can you share the details of your serializer(s)?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't measuring the time `json.dumps()` takes. You're measuring the times for

- the database and Django ORM
- the AReportSerializer taking to form the data (which happens when you access `serializer.data`)
- the actual JSON serialization.

```
start = time.process_time()
items = Allotment.objects.all().order_by("dispatch_date")
print("allotments", len(items))
print("query time", time.process_time() - start)
serializer = AReportSerializer(items, many=True)
data = serializer.data
print("data time", time.process_time() - start)
items_json = json.dumps(data)
print("json time", time.process_time() - start)
```

would be closer to the truth there.

Either way, if even that benchmarking does prove that it's `json.dumps` taking its sweet time, the [`orjson`](https://pypi.org/project/orjson/) library is a faster drop-in replacement for `json`...

Answer (score 1):

QuerySet's in Django are lazy. That means that while constructing a queryset, it will not make a query to fetch the results. It is in essence a class that *promises* to make a database call when you need these elements. For example when you enumerate over the items, determine its length, etc. This thus means that only when you call `len(items)` here, it will make the actual query.

The same happens when serializing. The serializer *promises* to generate a response for the `.data`, but it will not immediately do that when you construct the serializer. As long as this can be done when you actually need it, that is sufficient.

Furthermore serializers can produce an *N+1 problem* when you serialize data that is stored in a object linked to by a foreign key of the object you are rendering. In that case Django makes not one query, but *N+1* queries with `N` the number of `Allotment`s. The first query fetches all `Allotment`s, and then there are *N* queries to fetch a related object from the database. You can work with [**`.select_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) and [**`.prefetch_related(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) to fetch the data in the same query, or with one extra query. You thus should take a look what types of model objects are all fetched to generate the `serializer.data` data.

After optimizing the code, it might still eventually result in a large latency if the number of `Allotment` records starts growing. In that case *paginating* the content is advisable. It protects the server from rendering ineffective if a certain number of visitors want to retrieve all `Allotment`s in the same query.

Comment: Thankyou for such detailed explanation, I read the docs and go the understanding of when to use select/prefetch_related. However in my case the models are connected on much deeper level, I have removed extra fields and this is how my serializer looks now (Question edited)

Comment: @RahulSharma: what if you work with `.prefetch_related('flows', 'flows__kit')`?